# Azure Logic Apps error: The response is not in a JSON format

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to execute simple step from Azure Apps to get the pipeline run statistics, said pipeline calls Logic Apps in the Web activity:

[image]

However I'm receiving the error and I don't understand what exactly the step expects as input here:

[image]

Could you please assist in resolving above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use http requests to pass in your `Run Id`, because `Run Id` changes every time you run the pipeline.

You should use [Create a pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run) action first, then you can pass the run ID of the output of this operation to the Get a pipeline run action.

[image]

You can refer to this [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/158770/how-to-connect-a-pipeline-run-action-to-logic-app.html).

Comment: It does not make sense to me, because  "Get a pipeline run step" already receives all information about interested pipeline run (name and ID) from ADF directly and I don't want to start this pipeline within Logic Apps. I just wonder why it does not treat input values as valid...

Comment: I just wonder why it does not treat input values as valid, even if PipelineID is dynamically changes every time it is passed as some uniqueidentifier value, perhaps it requires some conversion or transformation for "Get a pipeline run step"..

Comment: It should be that `Get a pipeline run` action cannot find the pipeline running information of the runid you passed in. And return the data in non-json format, `Get a pipeline run` should receive the data in json format by default, and the data in non-json format will report an error when formatting.

Comment: seems yes, for me it is a bit weird behavior, but anyway the answer is found and the topic can be closed

Answer (score -1):

There should be a file identifier logic to be added it seems in your case:

[image]

You need to take the Output body of JSON file in next block.

Comment: Hi @Frank : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !